# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "NaN" at path "_id"

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, json-server

[
Issue now resolved... the answer was ridiculously simple...

$scope.article = articleFactory.getArticles().get({id:parseInt($stateParams.id,10)})
            .$promise.then(

should have read:

```
$scope.article = articleFactory.getArticles().get({
        id: $stateParams.id
    })
```

I did actually try this but for some reason Chrome was caching the old code - did a clear history and all was good.

Big "Doh".

]

I'm having a problem moving my site from json-server to express / mongo / mongoose. Everything is working fine on json but there appears to be an issue when I move it onto express / mongo / mongoose that throws up the following error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "NaN" at path "_id"
```

And then the server crashes...

I can stop the crash by modifying the route. formerly, it was this:

```
articleRouter.route('/:articleId')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
    Articles.findById(req.params.articleId, function (err, article) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(article);
    });

})
```

but if I add an if statement to filter out NaNs then the server runs:

```
articleRouter.route('/:articleId')
.get(function (req, res, next) {

if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        Articles.findById(req.params.articleId, function (err, article) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(article);
    });
}
})
```

But it doesn't serve up "detail pages" where the id is passed. I SUSPECT very strongly that this is something to do with types within mongoose schemas but I'm pretty new to this and am a bit lost.

The schema is as follows - I've tried it with and without the id field:

```
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
         unique: true,
         index: true
    },
    headline: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false
    }
---blah blah etc---
}
```

I've included ither code below whichb may or may not be relevant but I'm 95% that this is a Mongoose thing. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Stef

Relevant markup is:
(in "news.html")

```
<div ng-controller="ArticleController">
<div><a ui-sref="app.newsdetail({id: article.id})">See details</a></div>
</div>
```

Markup : (in "newsdetail.html")

```
<div ng-controller="ArticleDetailController">
{{article.headline}}
{{article.text}}
</div>
```

Controllers are:

```
.controller('ArticleController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'articleFactory', function ($scope, $stateParams, articleFactory) {
'use strict';
  articleFactory.getArticles().query(
      function(response) {
          $scope.articles = response;
      },
      function(response) {
          $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
      }
  );
}])

.controller('ArticleDetailController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'articleFactory', function ($scope, $stateParams, articleFactory) {
    $scope.article = {};

    $scope.article = articleFactory.getArticles().get({id:parseInt($stateParams.id,10)})
        .$promise.then(
            function(response){
                $scope.article = response;
                $scope.showArticle = true;
            },
            function(response) {
                $scope.message = "Error: "+response.status + " " + response.statusText;
            }
    );        
}])
```

And service is:

```
.service('articleFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL',      function($resource,baseURL) {
'use strict';
    this.getArticles = function(){ 
        return $resource(baseURL+"articles/:id",null,{'get':{method:'GET' }}); 
    }; 
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your schema you are defining the _id field, this is a "reserved" field, also it's of the type ObjectId you are defining String. You should remove the _id from your schema, it's added (and indexed) automaticly. 
Also see the [Mongoose schema documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that - I wasn;t sure. Sadly, I've tried it both with and without and the same error keeps occurring. Just baffled as to why it keeps throwing this error. Additionally, when I do it in json server - the id is passed in the url but not on express - probably something simple and dumb but am a bit stumped.

Comment: @user3607750 you can double check your collection to see the fields in the documents.

Comment: Yes have had a look... sample of collection: [
  {
    "_id": "580b31df24de442f78a5c9c8",
    "headline": "News item headline 0",
    "teaser_text": "Some teaser text",
    "teaser_image": "teaser.png",
    "text": "text for page",
    "image_1": "sample_1.png",
    "image_2": "sample_2.png",
    "image_3": "sample_3.png",
    "link_1": "http://www.test.com",
    "link_2": "http://www.test.com",
    "link_3": "http://www.test.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "updated": "2016-11-11T23:40:46.854Z"
  } - obviously there are loads of other records but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes looks like the problem is the _id in your document is a string, the .findById uses a objectid.

Comment: Okay... so how do I rectify that though... it seems to turn it into a string automatically.. is there a way of converting it to a suitable format? I mean, when i populate it the _id gets added automatically.

Comment: You can try it out to remove the _id from your schema and add a few documents, a find in shell should return { _id : ObjectId("xxxxxxxx"), Some fields } check out if your code can retrieve that document. Then you could do Some Migration remove the field from all docs and readd it. Hope its clear

Comment: Nope, tried that... same error. Have tried converting it to mongoose ObjectId in the route, same error: Articles.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.articleId), function (err, article) {

Comment: Could you print/log "req.params.articleId in your methode. Just to check it contains something.

Comment: Sorry if I appear a bit dumb... where should I actually print from? I've tried putting: console.log(req.params.articleId); in the route function as follows: .get(function (req, res, next) {

        Articles.findById(req.params.articleId, function (err, article) {
        console.log(req.params.articleId);
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(article);
    });
}) but nothing gets logged... like I say, I'm pretty new to this - thanks for your help thus far btw ;-)

Comment: Also, was just thinking, if its not preying on your time too much, might be easier to skype? Can do a screen share then and show you what I'm on about - don't know what the form is about that though and whether I've just committed a terrible faux pas  ;-)

Comment: You have to put it before Articles.findById because that function is failing. Or put it in the "if (err)" section

Comment: It's not even getting as far as the route... I added the following withing the if (err):                                                                                                   if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR THROWN");
            console.log(req.params.articleId);
        } and it's not printing out anything in the console... the actual screen just shows {{article.headline}} {{article.text}} etc... it seems to break down on the: <a ui-sref="app.newsdetails({id: article._id})">[DETAILS]</a> in the view which passes a NaN

Comment: Make the First line of your route method console.log("route entered, param" + req.params.articleId); to check if its entered.

Comment: Have done that - it doesn't log anything to the console. Just get "TypeError: n.get is not a function" which refers to the minified main.js file

Comment: Well then i guess its something in de angular part, i cannot help you with that :( you can use something like postman to check your api part is working.

Comment: Thanks anyway ;-) WIll get there in the end. Your help was much appreciated.